# Need my angular service to know when all component async operations have ended

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I have an angular service that owns an Observable. I have multiple (variable number) of components subscribed to it that react executing async operations. I need my service to know when all these component async operations have ended.

This is an approach of my situation:

**Filter Service**

```
...

appliedFilter$: Observable<FormattedFilter[]> = new Observable<FormattedFilter[]>(
    o => (this.appliedFilter = o)
  ).pipe(shareReplay(1));
  private appliedFilter: Observer<FormattedFilter[]>;

  onFiltersApplied(filters: Filter[]): void {
    if (this.appliedFilter) {
      const formattedFilters = this.formatFilters(filters);
      this.appliedFilter.next(formattedFilters);
    }
  }

...
```

**Filtrable Component 1**

```
...

this.filterService.appliedFilter$.subscribe(filters => {
  // multiple pipelined async operations
});

...
```

**Filtrable Component 2**

```
...

this.filterService.appliedFilter$.subscribe(filters => {
  // multiple pipelined async operations
});

...
```

**Filtrable Component 3**

```
...

this.filterService.appliedFilter$.subscribe(filters => {
  // multiple pipelined async operations
});

...
```

So what I need is the Filter Service to notice when all components have applied the received filters via appliedFilter$ Observable and when all the filtered data is finally loaded.

The aim of this is to prevent the user to update the filters before all components have finished their filtering process.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you need to wait till components will be updated instead of updateing components respectively to filter changes?
So if some component didn't updated while new filter is applied - let it just cancel current updates and do new. That is how usually good apps work.

Comment: @ArtemArkhipov I don't have any specific need. Yours seems a good approach. But I'm not sure how to cancel current updates as they can be pretty complex.

Comment: I posted an answer for you below

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: If you could create a minimal repro of your case it'd be easier to help you and show something concrete

Comment: I've updated my answer with one more example, please let me know if it helped.

Comment: @maxime1992 I don't have any repro because I'm in a design phase. So what best suits my needs here is a conceptual answer.

Comment: @ArtemArkhipov I'll let you know in the following days. Thanks!

Comment: @Mochics ok but then can you give a bit more details about what exactly you're trying to achieve? "The aim of this is to prevent the user to update the filters before all components have finished their filtering process" is not really clear to me

Comment: @maxime1992 The case is that I have several filters that can be combined and all these filters update several components. My aim was to block the filtering feature until all pending async operations were resolved. This has not turned out to be the best approach as, in my opinion, ArtemArkhipov pointed out a better one which is to cancel all pending requests if a new filter is selected. Hope my intentions has been cleared out now.

Comment: Oh I see thanks. Yes Artem answer seems to be a good fit!

Comment: @maxime1992 Thanks anyway!

Comment: @ArtemArkhipov It works. Nice approach, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you need to wait till components will be updated instead of updating components respectively to filter changes? 
In majority of nice, user-friendly apps approach seems to be different:
If some component didn't finish updating while new filter applied - updates are just cancelled and started new.

In your case it can be achieved using rxjs [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) operator. This operator allows you do exactly what I just said - give up on current async operations and start new if new emit comes.

Here is an example:

```
...

this.filterService.appliedFilter$
    .pipe(
        switchMap(
            filters => { return yourObservableChain()} // chain is your async opeartions
        )
    )
    .subscribe(); // you have only the most relevant values here

...
```

So, what going here:

1. When new filter is applied `yourObservableChain` is called (it can be http request or any other things you mean when you said (async operations).
2. If during those operations new filter applied again - those old would be ignored, calls would be cancelled and new operations will start.
3. Only the most relevant result will come to the `subscribe`.

*Note*, that switchMap **must** return an observable. Here is one more short example of its usage in scope of Angular (with http calls).

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'; // don't forget

... your components code:...

this.triggerSubject$.pipe( // assume this emits with some urls
    switchMap(data => { // assume new url is a prop of data
      return this.http.get(data.URL); // returns observable
    })
).subscribe(results => {
   // having only fresh results here
   // because switchMap cancelled other requests
   console.log(results) // or do whatever you need
})
```